# Why does the X-Files have 2 different opening sequences?

Tags: the-x-files

I've noticed that the X-Files has 2 different opening credit sequences: one with those weird growing goo fern things and the text "Paranormal Activity" and one without.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The opening sequence stayed the same from Season 1 through Season 7 (Duchovny left). With Season 8, Robert Patrick was added, pictures of Mulder and Scully were updated and other images were altered. Season 9 saw a completely new opening sequence.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files#Opening_title_sequence

Comment: I think there were a few minor variations along the way though, weren’t there? Like the text “The truth is out there” was sometimes substituted with something else.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Indeed, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files#Opening_sequence) has a small list. And that is not to mention internationalized versions; e.g. the German version of the intro would always show the episode title instead of a generic tagline where the original version had *The truth is out there.*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite They did subtly change the opening theme each season. More echoes and things like that.